# Excel 2007 error: You cannot add a calculated item to a grouped field. Can I work around this in anyway? VBA maybe?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, pivot-table, vba

I have tried to divide an item by another item. I group Date by Month and year and then I get this error "You cannot add a calculated item to a grouped field". I have tried everything except VBA.

Is there a way around this without VBA or is VBA my answer!

Comment: You can't do that with or without VBA. A simple solution is to add month and year fields to your source data.

Comment: Thanks! I got it working now!

Comment: Please add your solution and mark it answered.  It helps others and those of us looking for unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to make the individual items into columns. There isn't a way to calculate items with grouped data. I don't have code to post I had to do it manually.